# Move virtual object with x meters on axis. ARKIT Swift

Tags: arkit

I want to set a refernce point in scene, and place object at 5 meters from the reference point on X axis from example. Basically, i want to move an object without tap gesture and just using how many meters in front,right, my object should be put. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first run an `ARSession` the `worldOrigin` is set at `SCNVector3(0,0,0)`.

[image]

As such you can determine an initial reference point based on this.

For example placing an object 1m to the right of the XAxis, 0m on the YAxis and -1.5 away from the camera would be done like so:

```
 let nodeToAdd = SCNNode()
 let nodeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
 nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
 nodeToAdd.geometry = nodeGeometry
 nodeToAdd.position = SCNVector3(1, 0, -1.5)
 augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToAdd)
```

You can then move an SCNNode in many ways; with a very simple method being the use of an `SCNAction` which is:

> A simple, reusable animation that changes attributes of any node you attach it to.

Actions which move an SCNNode are as follows:

[image]

In our case therefore, let's make use of the class func:

```
 move(to: SCNVector3, duration: TimeInterval)
```

Which simply moves our node to a new position:

```
let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(1.5, 0, -1.5), duration: 5)
nodeToAdd.runAction(moveAction)
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)